# Query runs in PHPMyAdmin but not from PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, database

Why might this happen? The following query runs when I paste it into PHPMyAdmin but not when I run it from a php file:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM downloads WHERE downloadkey = '{$key}' LIMIT 1
```

This is the output on the webpage:

> Connected to database. The SELECT query failed. :

I also tried

```
$chk = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM downloads");
```

Which also runs in PHPMyAdmin but not from the file. Same output on webpage.

Below is the code. I tried different variations of `'{$key}'`:

```
'$key'  
{$key}  
$key
```

Same output each time.

```
$res = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
if (!$res) {
    echo mysql_errno($res) . ": " . mysql_error($res). "\n";
}
else {
    echo "Connected to database." . "\n";
}

mysql_select_db("database", $res);
$key = md5(microtime()); 
$chk = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM downloads WHERE downloadkey = '{$key}' LIMIT 1");
//$chk = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM downloads");
if (!$chk) {echo "The SELECT query failed." . "\n"; echo mysql_errno($chk) . ": " . mysql_error($chk) . "\n";}
```

Comment: You really need to share some of your code with us for us to be able to help you fix it. As of right now we don't even know what type of database connection code you are using, so how can we tell you how to display errors from it?

Comment: I get it. I hope the code I posted clarifies the problem.

Comment: It's really hardly fair to the person who provided you with the answer to your original question to completely change the question! You should roll-back your edit and give him the credit he deserves. Then post a NEW question with the new information.

Comment: I definitely give him credit, and I appreciate him posting a response. The reason I edited my question is that the moderators pointed out it didn't fit the guidelines: "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question." What I did is isolate the exact problem so that people don't have to wade through a lot of code.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
function getConnection( ) {

    $host="YOUR HOST";
    $port=3306;
    $socket="";
    $user=" ";
    $password=" ";
    $dbname="your db name";

    @ $con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket);

    if ( mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "false";
        return false;

    } else {

        return $con;
    }
}
```

You can call this function, it will return false if there was an error on the connection, and will return a Mysqli object if the connection was successful so you can interact with your database.

Comment: Thanks, I added my code above, which I hope will make my difficulty clearer.

Comment: mysql_connect is deprecated, please use mysqli functions or PDO! This is the way you can connect using mysqli:  
There are few solutions for your problem.

The way with MySQLi would be like this:
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Let us know how it goes.

Comment: I put this in my code. I appreciate you giving me the code for this. Although it doesn't solve the problem, it'll be useful later when I find the solution. What I mean is, the connection is successful. The connection was successful before as well. The problem seems to be with select (or any query I've tried), so I'm looking there for what the problem could be.

Comment: Ok, I've switched to the object-oriented approach, and now I'm getting an interesting error message. After successfully connecting and creating a mysqli object, the error message is telling me that I'm calling query() on a non-object. Should I post my code here, or should I open a new question?

Comment: Success! I have the whole thing working now --- connecting, selecting and inserting. I just had to change to the mysqli object. Thank you, Nick!

Comment: I'm glad it work! Have fun using Mysqli, it's a lot better than the old mysql extension